# How can I print the volume of one polyhedron based on what users inputs?

Tags: python, if-statement, volume

Write a program that reads the first capital letter ("T", "C", "O", "D" or "I") of the polyhedron the size of a side and which prints the volume of the corresponding polyhedron. If the letter read is not one of the 5 letters, your program prints "Unknown Polyhedron".

This prints almost every input value as the value of "else statement" but it should print the volume of the polyhedron based on the letter that user inputs and also the measure of the side.

```
import math
p = str(input())
a = float(input())
T = (math.sqrt(2) / 12) * (a ** 3)
C = a ** 3
O = (math.sqrt(2) / 3) * (a ** 3)
D = (15 + 7 * math.sqrt(5)) / 4 * (a ** 3)
I = 5 * (3 + math.sqrt(5)) / 12 * (a ** 3)
if p == (math.sqrt(2) / 12) * (a ** 3) :
    print (T)
elif p == a ** 3 :
    print(C)
elif p == (math.sqrt(2) / 3) * (a ** 3) :
    print(O)
elif p == (15 + 7 * math.sqrt(5)) / 4 * (a ** 3) :
    print(D)
elif p == 5 * (3 + math.sqrt(5)) / 12 * (a ** 3) :
    print(I)
else :
    print('Polyèdre non connu')
```

Comment: What you want and what you have written in the code is a bit confusing. Try to explain what you want more clearly

Comment: What exactly are you checking in these if statements? You're just repeating yourself from what you set to the `T`, `C`, etc variables. If you are wanting to check if the `p` string value is equal to the string `"T"` then just check `if p == "T":`

Comment: Consider having the `if` statement discriminate the letter input.  It will clean up the logic, and put all the "math" together.

Comment: Well, the program must calculate the area of a polyhedrone there are 5 polyhedrone types and each polyhedrone has a name (T, C, O, D and I). The user should input one of these letters and the measure of the side to calculate the volume of the polyedhrone, each polyhedrone has it's own formula. If the user inputs another letter, other than those above, the program should output the message "Unknown Polyhedrone".

Comment: @Daniel: I understood the problem now. Check my solution below. It might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a corrected working version of what you want

```
import math
p = input("Enter type of polyhedral: ")
a = float(input("Enter the value of a: "))

if p == 'T':
    volume =(math.sqrt(2) / 12) * (a ** 3)
elif p == 'C':
    volume = a**3
elif p == 'O':
    volume = (math.sqrt(2) / 3) * (a ** 3)
elif p == 'D':
    volume = (15 + 7 * math.sqrt(5)) / 4 * (a ** 3) 
elif p == 'I':
    volume =  5 * (3 + math.sqrt(5)) / 12 * (a ** 3)
else:
    print('Polyèdre non connu')
    volume = "Not Yet Defined"

print ("The volume of p=%s is %s" %(p, volume))
```

**Sample output**

```
Enter type of polyhedral: O
Enter the value of a: 12.45
The volume of p=O is 909.71

Enter type of polyhedral: K
Enter the value of a: 12
Polyèdre non connu
The volume of p=K is Not Yet Defined
```

Comment: Got it! This is  what i was looking for, but can you, please, explain a little the last line of code?

Comment: In the last line of the code, I am just printing the volume and the type of polyhedra. To do so, you use the format `%s` for printing a string. I am printing the type as `p=%s` and the volume also as a string using `is %s`. After defining the data type (%s for string), you have to put the values which will replace the strings `%s` in the double quotes. I have used %s for volume because I am using `volume = "Not Yet Defined"` when the polyhedra is different from what you want to calculate.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me.

Comment: One more thing, the code runs just perfect but there is one error on the last line.

Comment: What kind of error? Please write the input you used which caused error too

Comment: Results
ok The call to your program on input "O↵1.5↵" returned:
1.5909902576697321
ok The call to your program on input "O↵2.5↵" returned:
7.365695637359871
ok The call to your program on the input "C↵4.5↵" returned:
91125
ok The call to your program on the input "I↵4.0↵" returned:
139.6284793999944
ok The call to your program on the input "D↵1.0↵" returned:
7.663118960624632
ok The call to your program on input "O↵4.5↵" returned:
42.95673695708277
fail The code includes errors:
Line 19: name 'volume' is not defined

Comment: Are you using some sort of for loop? It looks your code works for most of the values. Can you tell me exactly for what value of `p` and `a` do you get error?

Comment: I changed a bit the code because i didn't need it as it was written, but only minor changes like excluding the text near inputs and using only the "print(volume)" because this is how i had to write it.

Comment: This error is not for values but for the volume, it says volume is not defined on the last line which i changed to be print(volume)

Comment: Yes, it seems that you entered some value of `p` for which there is no if, elif, else case and so no line where you write `volume=....` and therefore when you go out of the if statement, the `volume` is not calculated and therefore you get the error

Comment: If you wish you can paste the modified code here and I will try to see what's wrong. Without looking at your modified code, it's hard to guess what you modified

Comment: import math
p = input()
a = float(input())

if p == 'T':
    volume =(math.sqrt(2) / 12) * (a ** 3)
elif p == 'C':
    volume = a**3
elif p == 'O':
    volume = (math.sqrt(2) / 3) * (a ** 3)
elif p == 'D':
    volume = (15 + 7 * math.sqrt(5)) / 4 * (a ** 3)
elif p == 'I':
    volume =  5 * (3 + math.sqrt(5)) / 12 * (a ** 3)
else :
    print('Polyèdre non connu')

print (volume)

Comment: Ok, I got it. Just add the following line `if p in ['T', 'C', 'O', 'D', 'I']:    
    print (volume)` at the end. The problem was that when you enter some polyhedra which is not computed, there is no volume in the last `else:` part and hence when you print volume, you get error. The above lines will fix it

Comment: Yep, this is it. Thanks a lot! :)